# CMake IF(something OR something else)

Tags: cmake, expression, conditional-statements

Does the CMake `IF` statement have an `OR` option as well?  Something like: `IF (NOT this OR that) ... ENDIF`?

I have the line `if (NOT ${TARGET_PLATFORM} STREQUAL "test")`, which removes certain build files from the project.  I want to add a second Target platform option, "my_board", which needs to remove those same build files.  I tried adding an `elseif(NOT ${TARGET_PLATFORM} STREQUAL "my_board")` following the first `IF`, but that was not successful.

Is what I am trying to do possible with CMake, and if so, what is the proper syntax?

Thanks

Comment: Answered my own question.  Capital OR works just fine!  For my example the solution would be:  if (NOT (${TARGET_PLATFORM} STREQUAL "test" OR  ${TARGET_PLATFORM} STREQUAL "my_board"))

Comment: The cmake online documentation is great, make liberal use of it.  [cmake:if command](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake2.6docs.html#command:if) breaks down the whole thing.

Comment: You can answer your own question and mark it as "solved" =).

Answer (score 57):

```
if (NOT (${TARGET_PLATFORM} STREQUAL "test" OR ${TARGET_PLATFORM} STREQUAL "my_board"))
```

or more simply

```
if (CONDITION1 OR CONDITION2)
```